# C# Excel Reading optimization

Tags: c#, excel, optimization

My app will build an item list and grab the necessary data (ex: prices, customer item codes) from an excel file.

- This reference excel file has 650 lines and 7 columns.
- App will read rows of 10-12 items in one run-time.

Would it be wiser to read line item by line item?
Or should I first read all line item in the excel file into a list/array and make the search from there?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to start by designing the classes that best represent the data regardless of where it comes from. Pretend that there is no Excel, SQL, etc.

If your data is always going to be relatively small (650 rows) then I would just read the whole thing into whatever data structure you create (your own classes.) Then you can query those for whatever data you want, like

```
var itemsIWant = allMyData.Where(item => item.Value == "something");
```

The reason is that it enables you to separate the query (selecting individual items) from the storage (whatever file or source the data comes from.) If you replace Excel with something else you won't have to rewrite other code. If you read it line by line then the code that selects items based on criteria is mingled with your Excel-reading code.

Keeping things separate enables you to more easily test parts of your code in isolation. You can confirm that one component correctly reads what's in Excel and converts it to your data. You can confirm that another component correctly executes a query to return the data you want (and it doesn't care where that data came from.)

---

With regard to optimization - you're going to be opening the file from disk and no matter what you'll have to read every row. That's where all the overhead is. Whether you read the whole thing at once and then query or check each row one at a time won't be a significant factor.